# Reduced font size of bootstrap table contents

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to reduce the font-size of my bootstrap table.

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-condensed">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Hans</td>
        <td>Der</td>
        <td>Man</td>     
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here my CSS:

```
/* tables */

.table {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: none;
}

.table-condensed{
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

The problem am having is that the `table-condensed` property only seems to affect the table header row and not the rest of the rows.
[image: image showing different font size in header row with the rest of the rows]

I am wondering why `tbody` is not picking the font-size specified by `table-condensed`. Any ideas?